# I have [mixed] feelings about this tag…

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I ran across the [mixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mixed) tag yesterday by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56947430/coq-create-a-super-type-of-boolean-and-nat). I thought "it sounds like it's pretty much [mixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mixed) up" (pun intended) and looked through [questions tagged mixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mixed). It has 200 questions, but no tag wiki, and the question topics seem to vary wildly (based on the 1st page of search results):

- Many questions seem to be about mixed statistical models, and using it in various stats packages

  - Some of the questions talk about "mixed effect models", does that count here too? I'm not sure.
- A few are about mixed data types (also tagged with [types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/types))
- A few are about mixed precision
- A few are about audio?
- The rest are... just *anything* [mixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mixed) up.

And [searching for `[mixed*]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mixed-models+or+mixed-mode+or+mixed-content+or+mixed+or+mixed-integer-programming+or+mixed-code+or+mixed-programming+or+mixed-authentication+or+mixed-case+or+mixed-radix+or+mixed-type) reveals lots of `mixed-anything` tags.

- [mixed-models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mixed-models) sounds good for replacement to [mixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mixed) for many questions
- but the rest have only up to 200s of questions, and some don't even have tag wiki. The tags by themselves seem pretty bogus to me, e.g. what is [mixed-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mixed-code) supposed to be about?

Comment: Suggested title: Results on this tag are [mixed]

Comment: @Machavity little variation: *No more [mixed] results!*

Comment: I have [mixed] feelings about this tag...

Comment: I'm getting mixed messages about this.

Comment: add some confusion into the mix ...

Answer (score 13):

This tag is ambiguous, and has multiple meanings in multiple contexts. @Machavity already pointed out this tag's use for [mixed-type]. It's also used quite frequently for [mixed models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model). In this case, many of the questions use [mixed] and [model] as tags, rather than just using [mixed-model].

While this tag is being used for on-topic questions, it's ambiguous enough that it doesn't add anything of value.

That being said, this tag meets 3 of the 4 burnination criteria (ambiguous, no added meaning, and does *not* mean the same thing in all common contexts). I say we burn it.

Answer (score 9):

My first thought here was the `mixed` return type (i.e. you get back an array or null), but it seems like the usage here is all over the place. Many of these questions are unclear how [mixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mixed) applies ([case in point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55079298/chartjs-add-dots-to-bars-in-grouped-bar-chart)).

[mixed-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mixed-type) is what should be used for some of these questions, particularly those tagged [mixed] and [type] ([i.e. this list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmixed%5D+%5Btypes%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0)). A lot could simply have the tag dropped and not affect them at all.

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be [tag:union-types]?

Comment: @Deduplicator For some languages yes. PHP doesn't have them, tho, and I doubt it's the only one